# brace-or-equal-initializers initialization order

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

If using brace-or-equal-initializers, what's the initializing order of member variables? Are they initialize the same as code order?

```
struct foo {
    int x = 1;
    int y = x + 1;
} bar;
```

Will `bar.y` always be `2` regardless of the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `y` is guaranteed to be initialized after `x`. Non-static data members are always [initialized in order of their declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order) in the class definition, regardless of how they're initialized (by [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) or [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), even [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)).

> 3) Then, non-static data member are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

From Scott Meyers book, [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), item 4:

> One aspect of C++ that isn’t fickle is the order in which an object’s
>   data is initialized. This order is always the same: base classes are
>   initialized before derived classes (see also Item 12), and within a
>   class, data members are initialized in **the order in which they are
>   declared**.